# How to render nested routes with multiple optional params and path placeholders?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, path-to-regexp

I've been trying to use `react-router` to define a series of nested components/routes w/ optional params, but also separated by path placeholders.

i.e.

```
/list
/list/1
/list/items
/list/1/items
/list/1/items/1
```

I would assume the two `<Route>` paths would be something like:

```
/list/:listId?
and
`${match.url}`/items/:itemId?`
```

But alas.. `"items"` always ends up being accepted as the `listId` param, and therefore, the sub-routing for `/items` never matches.

I have a generic example I've coded here (doesn't accomplish a solution): https://stackblitz.com/edit/nesting-w-optional-params-react-router

I see examples all over the internet for `/root/:id1?/:id2?` but nothing for what I'm trying to do where I have a placeholder between the params: `/root/:id1/placeholder/:id2`.

Is this possible to do w/ `react-router` v4+ ??

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution utilizing RR's `children` pattern, to *always* render the nested route/component, but then inside the component use `path-to-regexp` directly to do route matching and to grab relevant route params from `props.location.pathname`.

Relevant bit of code:

```
render() {
    const pathRe = new PathToRegexp('/foo/:fooId?/bar/:barId?')
    const match = pathRe.match(this.props.location.pathname)
    if (!match) {
      return null
    }
    const barId = (this.props.match && this.props.match.params.barId) || match.barId
    return <h1>Bar <em>{barId}</em></h1>
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nesting-w-optional-params-react-router-solution